# Can't get a new category attribute value

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, category-attribute

I have added a new category attribute but after creating attribute, Im not able to fetch value...

A custom attribute is visible on the backend but how could I get value. I have followed this tutorial.

https://www.atwix.com/magento/add-category-attribute/

Comment: Have you well your custom attribute in category admin ? and are you well saving the data ?

Comment: data is getting a store in the database. and  custom_attribute field is also stored in the eva_attribute table. but not able to fetch the value.

Answer (score 0):

From the moment the attribute is well saved in the database, you should get it:

1. Try to reindex All
2. Try this:

   ```
   $categoryId = 112; //for exemple.
   $myCustomAttribute = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId)->getData('custom_attribute_name');

   Zend_Debug::dump($myCustomAttribute);
   ```

Comment: I Have tried this print_r(Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_category->getId())->getData());  'custom_attribute_name' is not showing there.

Comment: Please check the screenshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/TIZLY.png

Comment: Did you try to reindex ? try also to clean cache then try again

Comment: i have cleared all the cache and reindexing too..

Comment: In your config.xml try to update `<class>Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Setup</class>` to `<class>Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Setup</class>`

Comment: I have also tried this. But not able to get the response.

Comment: Could you please try this and let us know Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/category')->getAttributeRawValue($_category->getId(), "your-attribute", Mage::app()->getStore()->getId());

Answer (score -1):

```
Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/category')->getAttributeRawValue($_category->getId(), "custom_attribute", Mage::app()->getStore()->getId());
```